# Leave While Loop?

Tags: c#

I can't get out of the While Loop in my code and out of the method. The user has the option to enter 1 or 2 and 0 to cancel(to leave the menu and the method). But as the code are now, I guess the default option in the Switch prevent it from leaving the While Loop!? Can I do it in another and better way?

```
        // Read user input
    public void ReadUserInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Your choice? ");
        int choice = -1;
        while (choice != 0)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
            {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:           
                    ShowSchedule(1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ShowSchedule(2);
                    break;

                default:
                    ErrorMessage(); // Call method to show error message
                    ReadUserInput(); // Call method for new input
                    break;      
            }
            }
            else
            {
                // Call method to show error message
                ErrorMessage();
                Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code execution and observed the value of your variable through the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a

```
case 0:
    break;
```

to exit the loop if the user inputs 0. If there is indeed no code that should run after the loop in the method, you can also directly return from it with

```
case 0:
    return;
```

Comment: Won't that break the `switch` and not the `while`?

Comment: @moguzalp I think 'breaks `while` as well' is not the official terminology for exiting a loop by having the condition evaluate to false, but yeah, that's the point.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working! Now I don't get an error message if the user enter 4 or any unwanted signs like an A ?

Comment: How that? If the user inputs 4, the default branch is taken, with error message and repetition. If 'A' is input, `TryParse` returns false, so the `else` branch gives the error message. If it behaves differently with that code, it's a bug in the framework (very unlikely).

Comment: If 0 is the first number to be entered it works, but if I enter 2 and then when it waits for a new choice and I enter 0 it just ask for new choice!?

Comment: Not here. If I try it here and enter 0 at any time, it exits, as it should.

Comment: The problem is solved! I was a call to a method that initated the method with the input. Now it works fine without case 0: return and I guess it should be working without when the While statement is waiting for a 0 to be entered. Right? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to break `swicth` **and** `while`, just use `return` keyword here:

```
while (choice != 0)
{
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
    {
       switch (choice)
       {
            case 0:
               return; //returns from the FUNCTION! So from the switch AND while
            ....

            ....

            ....
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine the first time, but when I enter 0 the third time, after a 1 or 2 has been entered, it's not working!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ:not very clear how your user interaction works, so. Are you sure, that after "1", "2" the `Console.ReadLine()/ReadChar()` called again in order to get from the user a new input?

Comment: The problem is solved! I was a call to a method that initated the method with the input. Now it works fine without case 0: return and I guess it should be working without when the While statement is waiting for a 0 to be entered. Right? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the initial `Console.Write()` inside your loop, don't call `ReadUserInput()` recursively.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working. If I enter 0 it still ask for new input?

Comment: Worked for me - are you sure you removed the extra `ReadUserInput()` call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `return` keyword to exit the function entirely.

Comment: Wherever you want to leave the method, of course. I suppose this would be in the default section, before the break (or perhaps instead of it).